# Scraping strings for numbers

Tags: node.js, string

So I have a bunch of strings that look like this:

```
var string = "0.1 - 1";
```

I'd like to pull out the value that's to the left of ***"-"*** as well as the value to the right. In this case that would be:
leftValue = 0.1, rightValue = 1. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: please make an attempt before asking, use `split`

Comment: How do you define numbers? Is `-1` a number? `1e3`? What about the operators - is it `-` only? Other operators? Do you always have whitespace? Is it optional, as in you can have `0.1--1`? What happens with invalid input? Any other parsing rules? can you have more than a single expression, e.g, nested ones `(0.9 - 0.8) - (0.5 + 0.5)`? Can you have a longer expression: `0.1 - 1 + 2`?

Comment: values range from 0 to 1, so they will all be between "0 - 1". They ALL have the - and same amount of white spaces. The only difference are the numbers on both sides.@depperm already did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work assuming your string is always a number, a dash, and another number. It will not work with negative numbers since it splits on all dash characters.

```
var string = "0.1 - 1";
var splitStr = string.split("-");
var leftValue = parseFloat(splitStr[0]);
var rightValue = parseFloat(splitStr[1]);
```